# Is this normal behaviour in php arrays? Array size get shortened when using numbered indexes out of order

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm learning Php, so as I was messing around with arrays to see how they work, I stumbled into this when I made two arrays.

```
$TestArray1 = array( 1 => 1, "string" => "string", 24, "other", 2 => 6, 8);    
$TestArray2 = array( 6 => 1, "string" => "string", 24, "other", 1 => 6, 8);
```

But when I print them out with print_r() this is what I get (this also happens with var_dump by the way)

```
Array ( [1] => 1 [string] => string [2] => 6 [3] => other [4] => 8 )

Array ( [6] => 1 [string] => string [7] => 24 [8] => other [1] => 6 [9] => 8 )
```

As far as I can tell, by putting the two in the second array it overwrites the next possible spot with no key and then keeps going, shortening the array. So I thought that meant that if I use a 1 it would put it at the start but that does not happen either.

Is this normal or is there something wrong with my php installation?
Im using Ampps in windows 10 with php 7.3.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

What's happening is that when determining automatic numeric indexes, PHP will look to the largest numeric index added and increment it (or use `0` if there are none).

> The key is optional. If it is not specified, PHP will use the increment of the largest previously used integer key.

What's happening with your first array is that as it is evaluated left-to-right, `24` is inserted at index `2` because the last numeric index was `1 => 1`.

Then when it gets to `2 => 6`, it overwrites the previous value at index `2`. This is why `24` is missing from your first array.

> If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.

Here's a breakdown

```php
$TestArray1 = [1 => 6]; // Array( [1] => 6 )

// no index, so use last numeric + 1
$TestArray1[] = 24;     // Array( [1] => 6, [2] => 24 )

$TestArray1[2] = 6;     // Array( [1] => 6, [2] => 6 )
```

When you manually add numeric indexes that are lower than previous ones (ie `$TestArray2`), they will be added as provided but their *position* will be later.

This is because PHP arrays are really maps that just pretend to be indexed arrays sometimes, depending on what's in them.

---

References are from the [PHP manual page for Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/language.types.array.php)